# Detect 100% CPU load by a referenced library

Tags: c#, dll, process

I have a ASP.NET (C#) website that uses a third party DLL to process the data that the users POST via a web form. The call is pretty straightforward:

```
string result = ThirdPartyLib.ProcessData(myString);
```

Once in a blue moon this library hangs and (according to my hosting provider logs) consumes 100% of CPU. The website is hosted on a shared hosting, so I have no access to the IIS or event logs. When this happens, my website is automatically stopped by the hosting provider performance monitor, and I have manually switch it back on.

Now, I know that the right thing to to is investigate the problem and fix (or replace) the DLL. But as it's third-party software, I am unuable to fix it, and their support is not helpful at all. Moreover, I can't reproduce the problem. Replacing the library is a pain too.

Is there a way in C# to detect when this DLL starts consuming 100%CPU and kill the process automatically from my ASP.NET code?

Comment: is the `ThirdPartLib.ProcessData(myString)` do you know the method / class signature is it a public class or a static class..? are there disposing issues going on.. can you have the 3rd party debug / fix the code..? can you as well show how you are consuming / instantiating the instance of the 3rd part class object..?

Comment: @MethodMan, `is it a public class or a static class..?` It's a public non-static class that has a single parameterless ctor & a single method I need to call. `are there disposing issues going on` The lib doesn' expose any IDisposable classes.  `can you have the 3rd party debug / fix the code..?` The answer is much closer to 'no' than to 'yes'. If I could get a fix, I would obviously use it. `can you as well show how you are consuming / instantiating the instance` There's nothing to show, really. The public methods of the lib are obvious and there's no way to mis-use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "detect" if the current process is hanging because as the caller of a method (third party or not) you're simply not in control until it returns.

What you can do is move the call to the third party library into a separate executable and have it output its result via the standard output (you can simply use `Console.WriteLine(string)` for this).

Once you've done that, you can start a separate [`Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ty0d8k56(v=vs.110).aspx) that runs this executable, read the result via [`StandardOutput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx) and use [`WaitForExit(int)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ty0d8k56(v=vs.110).aspx) to wait a certain amount of time (maybe a few seconds) for the process to finish. The return value of `WaitForExit()` tells you if the process actually exited. In case it didn't, you can [`Kill()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill(v=vs.110).aspx) it and move on without IIS worker process hanging as a whole.